# Zooming text in scatter plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Is there any way I can zoom text in scatter plot in matlab? Suppose I have following code:

```
x = 1:10; y = 1:10; scatter(x,y);
a = [1:10]'; b = num2str(a); c = cellstr(b);
dx = 0.1; dy = 0.1; 
text(x+dx, y+dy, c);
```

I want to zoom in and zoom out the text size of {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} associated with each datapoint when I click the zoom in our out button respectively. I am using matlab r2015b.

**Edit 1**
For example when I click the zoom in button c will also be zoomed in with rest of the figure and if I click zoomed out button c will also be zoomed out with rest of the figure[image]

Comment: I edit the question. and add a figure. Can you please check.

Answer (score 0):

When you have the graph open in MATLAB you should have a menu bar open at the top of the screen.

Select: View->Property Editor

From here you can click on the text you would like to edit and format size/colour/font using the GUI at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: The text 1 2 3 4 appears in the figure. I am not talking about x or y axis label. My question is how I can zoom the text that is in the plot (not as axis label) when I zoom in or out the figure

Comment: @jubair The answer is not exclusive to axis labels, it works fine for changing properties of the text objects as well.

Comment: If you want to do that way you always need to zoom in and zoom out manually. The question is not about how to handle this manually. The answer does not satisfy the question anyway. See the solution I posted below.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. We need to use the callback function of zoom `ActionPostCallback` and pass an additional parameter of text object. Then we need to adjust the zoom level from the callback.

```
f = figure
x = 1:10; y = 1:10; scatter(x,y);
a = [1:10]'; b = num2str(a); c = cellstr(b);
dx = 0.1; dy = 0.1; 
s = text(5, 5, 'c', 'fontsize',1);
h = zoom(f);

set(h, 'ActionPostCallback', {@mypostcallback,s});

function [ ] = mypostcallback(obj,event_obj,s)
xlim = event_obj.Axes.XLim;
fontsize = 10/(xlim(2)-xlim(1));
set(s,'fontsize',fontsize);

end
```